# Operations After UIAlert is dismissed causes dealays

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I am currently making a registration form for my App. Once the user hits the register button a alert is given to the user to to confirm the number and proceed.

Screenshot of Alert:

[image]

If the user hits cancel I perform the following operations:

```
/*** Reset Mobile Number Input ***/
                        self.flagMobileNumber = 0
                        self.validatorIconMobileNumber.setImage(nil, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        self.mobileNumberInput.text = ""
                        self.mobileNumberInput.becomeFirstResponder()

                    /*** Disable Register Button ***/
                        self.registerButton.alpha = 0.5
                        self.registerButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

But there is a considerable delay that occurs before all the operations are completed.

May someone explain why this happens and what can be done to prevent it.

Comment: What is a "considerable delay"? 0.5 seconds? 5 seconds? You haven't shown us your complete alert delegate method, are you sure the delay is caused by the code you've posted? If so, why? Hint: Try adding some `NSLog` calls at strategic points, they print the current time so you can see where the most time spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably aren't on the main thread, doing UI stuff on a different thread (other than the main thread) is discouraged, and usually takes time.

try doing your UI stuff on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// do UI stuff here
});
```